# How to squeeze in missing values into a vector

Tags: r

Let me try to make this question as general as possible.

Let's say I have two variables *a* and *b*.

```
a <- as.integer(runif(20, min = 0, max = 10))
a <- as.data.frame(a)
b <- as.data.frame(a[c(-7, -11, -15),])
```

So *b* has 17 observations and is a subset of *a* which has 20 observations.

My question is the following: how I would use these two variables to generate a third variable *c* which like *a* has 20 observations but for which observations 7, 11 and 15 are missing, and for which the other observations are identical to *b* but in the order of *a*?

Or to put it somewhat differently: how could I squeeze in these missing observations into variable *b* at locations 7, 11 and 15?

It seems pretty straightforward (and it probably is) but I have been not getting this to work for a bit too long now.

Comment: Do you actually have `a` and `b`, or are you able to go straight from `a` to `c` directly (do you have the instructions for creating `b`)?

Comment: Hi Joe, yes, I have _a_ and _b_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) loop** Try this loop:

```
# test data
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
a <- as.integer(runif(20, min = 0, max = 10))
a <- as.data.frame(a)
b <- as.data.frame(a[c(-7, -11, -15),])

# lets work with vectors
A <- a[[1]]
B <- b[[1]]

j <- 1
C <- A
for(i in seq_along(A)) if (A[i] == B[j]) j <- j+1 else C[i] <- NA
```

which gives:

```
> C
 [1]  2  7  4  8  9  0 NA  8  5  4 NA  4  6  5 NA  8  2  0  3  9
```

**2) Reduce** Here is a loop-free version:

```
f <- function(j, a) j + (a == B[j])
r <- Reduce(f, A, acc = TRUE)
ifelse(duplicated(r), NA, A)
```

giving:

```
[1]  2  7  4  8  9  0 NA  8  5  4 NA  4  6  5 NA  8  2  0  3  9
```

**3) dtw**.  Using `dtw` in the package of the same name we can get a compact loop-free one-liner:

```
library(dtw)

ifelse(duplicated(dtw(A, B)$index2), NA, A)
```

giving:

```
[1]  2  7  4  8  9  0 NA  8  5  4 NA  4  6  5 NA  8  2  0  3  9
```

**REVISED**  Added additional solutions.

Comment: I feel like there ought to be a non-loop version of this, but I guess that would only be true if you properly handled creation of `b` to keep track of which rows you were deleting.

Comment: @Joe, Have added a loop-free version.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Nice!

Comment: +1 as this is a good start, but it will return suboptimal results on more complicated examples - see e.g. the one in my answer

Comment: @eddi, My third answer can handle those.  Note that the complex example in your response does not have a unique answer and, in fact, the third alternative above does give a different but valid answer to it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck your 3rd answer still returns sub-optimal results for the example I gave (of course OP might not care about matching with minimal edit-distance, but if we are to add a benchmark on what's optimal - that's the obvious one you would add)

Comment: @eddi, There is no concept of optimality in the question. In fact there are multiple feasible solutions to your complex pattern.

Comment: I agree that one is not *specified* in the question. But matching largest chunks is the obvious optimality constraint, were you to start caring about more than just randomly matching.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more complicated way of doing it, using the Levenshtein distance algorithm, that does a better job on more complicated examples (it also seemed faster in a couple of larger tests I tried):

```
# using same data as G. Grothendieck:
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
a <- as.integer(runif(20, min = 0, max = 10))
a <- as.data.frame(a)
b <- as.data.frame(a[c(-7, -11, -15),])
A = a[[1]]
B = b[[1]]

# compute the transformation between the two, assigning infinite weight to 
# insertion and substitution
# using +1 here because the integers fed to intToUtf8 have to be larger than 0
# could also adjust the range more dynamically based on A and B
transf = attr(adist(intToUtf8(A+1), intToUtf8(B+1),
                    costs = c(Inf,1,Inf), counts = TRUE), 'trafos')

C = A
C[substring(transf, 1:nchar(transf), 1:nchar(transf)) == "D"] <- NA
#[1]  2  7  4  8  9  0 NA  8  5  4 NA  4  6  5 NA  8  2  0  3  9
```

More complex matching example (where the greedy algorithm would perform poorly):

```
A = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
B = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)

transf = attr(adist(intToUtf8(A), intToUtf8(B),
                    costs = c(Inf,1,Inf), counts = TRUE), 'trafos')

C = A
C[substring(transf, 1:nchar(transf), 1:nchar(transf)) == "D"] <- NA
#[1] NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  2  2  2

# the greedy algorithm would return this instead:
#[1]  1  1 NA NA  1 NA NA  2  2  2
```

Comment: Note that this solution depends on the fact that the components of `a` are each one digit.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck good point - a way to extend this to much larger integers is to use `intToUtf8` instead of `paste0` - will edit that in in a sec

Answer (score 2):

The data frame version, which isn't terribly different from G.'s above.
(Assumes a,b setup as above).

```
j <- 1
c <- a
for (i in (seq_along(a[,1]))) {
    if (a[i,1]==b[j,1]) {
        j <- j+1
        } else 
        {
        c[i,1] <- NA
        }

}
```