# Comparing elements within a list

Tags: r, dynamic, time

I have a list of 22 lists which contain two vectors.  Each of the vectors are of equal length within the 2nd list but are of unequal length with respect to each other.  See output of a dput at the end.

I want to build a data.frame by (i) finding the longest vector, (ii) comparing all the other 1st vectors of the list of 2 vectors with the first of the longest vector and filling any omissions with NA values.  I want to combine the resulting second vectors (including their NAs) in a data.frame.

(The data sets are relative retention times and percentage areas.  I want to compare all the chromatograms with one another).

I can answer the first part, (i), of my question using the following code,

```
max(sapply(lapply(A, function(x) x[1,]),length))
```

which tells me that the last data set in the list is the longest.

Now I want to stick the NAs in using dynamic time warping (dtw()) package and applying the answer (No 3) given here [dtw link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416899/how-to-squeeze-in-missing-values-into-a-vector/23417160#23417160) but I found that it only seemed to apply to vectors of the same length.

```
structure(list(chrom_a = structure(c(0.4663, 11.16, 0.4955, 0.82, 
0.8744, 4.92, 0.9101, 1.55, 1, 73.91, 1.2862, 5, 1.3198, 1.06, 
1.4302, 1.57), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", 
"rel.area"), c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))), chrom_b =structure(c(0.465, 
8.6, 0.4938, 0.64, 0.8714, 5.1, 0.907, 1.49, 1, 76.22, 1.2813, 
4.92, 1.3144, 1.03, 1.3704, 0.56, 1.4245, 1.45), .Dim = c(2L, 
9L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))), chrom_c = structure(c(0.4654, 
7.58, 0.4943, 0.58, 0.8724, 5.12, 0.9082, 1.51, 1, 77.05, 1.2835, 
4.97, 1.3168, 1.07, 1.3732, 0.57, 1.4272, 1.54), .Dim = c(2L, 
9L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))), chrom_d = structure(c(0.3841, 
0.28, 0.4638, 6.07, 0.4926, 0.48, 0.7903, 0.29, 0.8694, 4.79, 
0.9049, 1.38, 1, 67, 1.2783, 4.62, 1.3116, 0.95, 1.3681, 0.51, 
1.4215, 13.29, 3.5744, 0.35), .Dim = c(2L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"))), chrom_e = structure(c(0.5304, 
4.68, 0.8727, 5.34, 0.9086, 1.57, 1, 79.92, 1.2838, 5.22, 1.3168, 
1.13, 1.3742, 0.58, 1.4279, 1.57), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
    "8", "9"))), chrom_f = structure(c(0.3718, 0.36, 0.4628, 
3.38, 0.4915, 0.32, 0.789, 0.42, 0.8685, 6.15, 0.904, 1.72, 0.9399, 
0.34, 1, 74.63, 1.0651, 0.5, 1.1014, 0.35, 1.1266, 0.29, 1.1609, 
0.41, 1.2108, 0.32, 1.2774, 6.06, 1.3103, 1.36, 1.3667, 0.96, 
1.4201, 1.63, 3.5693, 0.48, 3.6497, 0.34), .Dim = c(2L, 19L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21"))), chrom_g = structure(c(0.465, 1.44, 0.8708, 
5.4, 0.9064, 1.53, 1, 82.64, 1.2805, 5.3, 1.3134, 1.16, 1.37, 
0.55, 1.4239, 1.54, 3.5792, 0.44), .Dim = c(2L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11"))), chrom_h = structure(c(0.4644, 7.08, 0.4932, 
0.55, 0.8708, 5.15, 0.9064, 1.49, 1, 77.57, 1.2805, 5.04, 1.3142, 
1.08, 1.3704, 0.53, 1.4245, 1.51), .Dim = c(2L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11"))), chrom_i = structure(c(0.4641, 6.82, 0.493, 
0.54, 0.8714, 5.24, 0.9075, 1.46, 1, 78.08, 1.2826, 4.91, 1.3164, 
1.02, 1.3722, 0.51, 1.4266, 1.41), .Dim = c(2L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11"))), chrom_j = structure(c(74.173, 31.69, 
0.3729, 0.25, 0.4637, 4.36, 0.4925, 0.35, 0.7904, 0.21, 0.8697, 
3.9, 0.9055, 1.06, 1, 52.76, 1.279, 3.56, 1.3119, 0.69, 1.369, 
0.3, 1.4224, 0.87), .Dim = c(2L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", 
"rel.area"), c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13"))), chrom_k = structure(c(0.4661, 5.91, 0.8743, 
5.23, 0.9105, 1.53, 1, 79.89, 1.2863, 5.11, 1.3822, 0.99, 1.0169, 
1.33), .Dim = c(2L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"
), c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))), chrom_l = structure(logical(0), .Dim = c(2L, 
0L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), NULL)), chrom_m = structure(logical(0), .Dim = c(2L, 
0L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), NULL)), chrom_n = structure(c(0.3793, 
0.37, 0.4604, 6.12, 0.4896, 0.49, 0.8709, 8.41, 0.9072, 1.46, 
1, 76.51, 1.2844, 4.75, 1.3188, 0.83, 1.429, 1.06), .Dim = c(2L, 
9L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))), chrom_o = structure(c(0.1252, 
43.23, 0.4625, 2.06, 0.8728, 3, 0.9094, 0.88, 1, 46.69, 1.2865, 
2.91, 1.3209, 0.54, 1.4306, 0.7), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
    "8", "9"))), chrom_p = structure(c(0.1248, 31.52, 0.3796, 
0.23, 0.4608, 1.18, 0.7891, 0.25, 0.8687, 3.88, 0.905, 1.04, 
1, 55.93, 1.2808, 3.72, 1.3149, 0.8, 1.3709, 0.38, 1.4244, 1.06
), .Dim = c(2L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"
), c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"
))), chrom_q = structure(c(0.4618, 0.74, 0.8702, 5.49, 0.9062, 
1.44, 1, 83.93, 1.2837, 5.21, 1.3181, 1.13, 1.3738, 0.53, 1.428, 
1.53), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"
), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))), chrom_r = structure(c(0.8715, 
5.39, 0.9072, 1.4, 1, 84.41, 1.2821, 5.18, 1.3151, 1.14, 1.3722, 
0.63, 1.4258, 1.46, 3.5918, 0.39), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10"))), chrom_s = structure(c(0.3722, 0.38, 0.4636, 
6.12, 0.492, 0.5, 0.7898, 0.42, 0.8687, 5.94, 0.9047, 1.69, 0.9403, 
0.33, 1, 73.12, 1.0642, 0.44, 1.1033, 0.32, 1.1276, 0.25, 1.162, 
0.33, 1.2787, 5.87, 1.3119, 1.32, 1.3685, 0.76, 1.422, 1.5, 3.5817, 
0.42, 3.662, 0.3), .Dim = c(2L, 18L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", 
"rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))), chrom_t = structure(c(0.3738, 
0.37, 0.4651, 1.51, 0.7917, 0.34, 0.8711, 5.49, 0.9071, 1.51, 
1, 81.91, 1.2834, 5.33, 1.3166, 1.13, 1.3736, 0.57, 1.4283, 1.41, 
3.6102, 0.43), .Dim = c(2L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", 
"rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13"))), chrom_u = structure(c(0.3844, 0.38, 0.4647, 2.2, 
0.7909, 0.37, 0.8699, 5.99, 0.906, 1.63, 1, 79.36, 1.2817, 5.86, 
1.3149, 1.23, 1.372, 0.67, 1.4257, 1.56, 3.6037, 0.45, 3.684, 
0.3), .Dim = c(2L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(c("rel.ret", "rel.area"
), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14"))), chrom_v = structure(c(0.3836, 0.45, 0.4644, 0.62, 0.7894, 
0.58, 0.8685, 7.17, 0.9043, 1.85, 0.941, 0.43, 1, 73.3, 1.0663, 
0.31, 1.0849, 0.23, 1.1035, 0.4, 1.1284, 0.31, 1.1625, 0.5, 1.2133, 
0.36, 1.2381, 0.32, 1.2795, 7.2, 1.3126, 1.64, 1.37, 1.13, 1.423, 
2.05, 3.5963, 0.71, 3.6776, 0.45), .Dim = c(2L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("rel.ret", "rel.area"), c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21", "22")))), .Names = c("chrom_a", "chrom_b", 
"chrom_c", "chrom_d", "chrom_e", "chrom_f", "chrom_g", "chrom_h", 
"chrom_i", "chrom_j", "chrom_k", "chrom_l", "chrom_m", "chrom_n", 
"chrom_o", "chrom_p", "chrom_q", "chrom_r", "chrom_s", "chrom_t", 
"chrom_u", "chrom_v"))
```

Comment: `which.max(lengths(A))` is all you need for the list with the longest length

Comment: @PierreLafortune are you sure this returns 22 not 20?

Comment: @PierreLafortune That's a neat trick with the `lengths()` in plural form.

Comment: But because you have a vector with dimensions (array) in each list element you will either have to divide by two or use the column names fot the row length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone about this in a slightly different way to the one you were originally pursuing but with the same end goal. My assumption is that you have a list of chromatograms with peaks that have a retention time and area and that you want to end up with a means of comparing peaks across the different chromatograms.

First convert to a long `data.table`:

```
chroms_long <- rbindlist(lapply(chroms, function(x) {
  as.data.table(t(x))
  }))
chroms_long[, chrom := rep(names(chroms), lengths(chroms) / 2)]
```

Then put into groups using hierarchical clustering. The cutoff `h` in this call needs to be varied for the underlying data, but for this dataset 0.015 seems right.

```
setkey(chroms_long, rel.ret, chrom)
chroms_long[, group := cutree(hclust(dist(rel.ret)), h = 0.015)]
```

If you wanted to now have a row for each possible chromatogram/group:

```
setkey(chroms_long, chrom, group)
chroms_long <- chroms_long[CJ(unique(chrom), unique(group))]
```

If you also want to know the mean retention time per group:

```
chroms_long[, mean_rel.ret := mean(rel.ret, na.rm = TRUE), by = group]
```

If you want the output in a wide format:

```
dcast.data.table(chroms_long, chrom ~ group, value.var = "rel.area")
```

If instead of group number you wanted the mean retention as the column header:

```
dcast.data.table(chroms_long[, .(chrom, col = sprintf("%0.2f", mean_rel.ret), rel.area)],
  chrom ~ col, value.var = "rel.area")
```

If you wanted to restore the original format:

```
sapply(unique(chroms_long$chrom),
  function(x) t(data.matrix(chroms_long[x, .(rel.ret, rel.area)])),
  simplify = FALSE)
```

Note this uses `sapply` for its `USE.NAMES` feature rather than for simplifying the output from a list.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it yet but from your preliminary comments you seem to 'grok' what I'm trying to do.  My chromatograms are cuts from various distillations: I want to check the purity profile as I'm going along; I want to ensure that my purity doesn't fall below a certain level.  Will check your code against the given data set this evening.  Thanks!

Comment: for some reason the code throws an error at, chroms_long <- chroms_long[CJ(unique(chrom), unique(group)] saying that Error: unexpected ']' in "chroms_long <- chroms_long[CJ(unique(chrom), unique(group)]" I'd fix it myself but I'm still working through the code.  Can you help?  Fixed it, it needed an extra parenthesis before the last square bracket.

Comment: @user1945827 missing bracket! now fixed

Comment: works for me.  Now need to go and learn data.table package to work out what's going on.  Thanks again.

Comment: re-visited your answer but I'm getting an 'Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length' ' error when doing the dcasting?  Is it my data?

Comment: changing the h value (ie the cut-off) cascaded through to give what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

```
mx <- tail(colnames(A[[which.max(lengths(A))]]),1)
newA <- lapply(A, function(x) apply(x, 1, function(x) {length(x) <- mx;x}))
```

This will extend the lengths of the rows to the maximum row length.

Comment: But there isn't a a sorting step using the dtw() function (or other function) to put the NAs in their appropriate places.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion that I think provides the desired output (if I understood the task correctly).

```
longest_vec <-  A[[which.max(lengths(A))]][1,]
m <- matrix(NA, ncol = as.integer(names(longest_vec[length(longest_vec)])), nrow = length(A))
for (i in 1:nrow(m)) m[i, as.integer(colnames(A[[i]]))] <- unname(A[[i]][2,])
df <- as.data.frame(m)
df <- df[,-1]
colnames(df) <- c(2, names(longest_vec))
#> head(df)
#      2    3    4     5     6     7    8     9    10   11   12    13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21 22
#1 11.16 0.82 4.92  1.55 73.91  5.00 1.06  1.57    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA NA
#2    NA 8.60 0.64  5.10  1.49 76.22 4.92  1.03  0.56 1.45   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA NA
#3  7.58 0.58 5.12  1.51 77.05  4.97 1.07  0.57  1.54   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA NA
#4    NA 0.28 6.07  0.48  0.29  4.79 1.38 67.00  4.62 0.95 0.51 13.29 0.35   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA NA
#5  4.68 5.34 1.57 79.92  5.22  1.13 0.58  1.57    NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA NA
#6    NA 0.36 3.38  0.32  0.42  6.15 1.72  0.34 74.63 0.50 0.35  0.29 0.41 0.32 6.06 1.36 0.96 1.63 0.48 0.34 NA
```

Hope this helps.

PS: I stole the first line of the code from an excellent comment by @Pierre Lafortune.

Comment: My problem is that I find it difficult to write an example solution hence you can't taylor your answers to what I need.  But thanks anyway.